# Impossible to install package after R upgrade to 4.2.1

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, installation, updates

I get errors when I want to install packages after upgrade of R to R4.2.1 on a ubuntu 22.04 computer. Error is pasted below.
Any package that I tried until now give this error.

```
> install.packages("prompt")
Installing package into ‘/home/simon/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/prompt_1.0.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 150849 bytes (147 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 147 KB

Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘prompt’
Calls: loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Execution halted

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpx1eUsz/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("prompt") :
  installation of package ‘prompt’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that I get the same error when I try to install prompt. I changed the example.

Comment: Do you have some sort of `.Rprofile` file or `.Renviron` file from your previous R installation in your user home directory? Seems like something non-standard is trying to load that package and is not checking if the package exists.

Comment: Agree with @MrFlick about possible source of the problem. Does running `R --vanilla` make the problem go away?

Comment: Yes ! @MrFlick : content of .Rprofile : ```prompt::set_prompt(function(...){
  paste0(
    "[", prompt::git_branch(), prompt::git_dirty(), prompt::git_arrows(), "] "
  )
})
```

Comment: @BenBolker Yes it does ! How do I solve this ? Remove Rprofile ?

Comment: @sbenateau. Well, you need to get rid of that. Or at least wrap it in `if (require(prompt)) {}` to only run that if the package is available and loaded. You can use that again after you install the `prompt` package.

Comment: If the comments have helped you solve the problem, it would be best if you wrote up your own solution to the problem and posted it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @MrFlick and @BenBolker, I found a solution.

I removed the .Rprofile file that was in my user home directory and that solved the problem.

Use the following command lines in your terminal :

```
less .Rprofile # to check what was inside the file (prompt was called)
rm .Rprofile # to remove the file
```

Comment: you might want to `mv .Rprofile Rprofile_old` in case you want to reuse/restore the material later ...